# How can I add HTML code on same capcha file in PHP?

Tags: php

I have created a captcha for my login system. It works and gives me captcha (random) code on the image but if I add HTML code above the captcha code the captcha doesn't work.

```
<h1> This is my HTML code </h1>

    <?php
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        $imgPath = 'background.jpg';
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 253, 253, 253);
        $string = rand();
       $fontSize = 14;
        $x = 30;
        $y = 15;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
        imagejpeg($image);
    ?>
```

How can I execute successfully HTML code in the same capcha.php file?

Comment: Put your captcha PHP into a separate file (e.g. captcha.php)  , and then use something like <img src='captcha.php'>

Comment: Yes, also I can do it with an iframe but this is nice. Thank you @KenLee

Comment: "the captcha doesn't work." - what does that mean? Why do you want to add markup to an image?

Comment: I was asking if I can do code in the same file. This is just a query. Now, I got my answer, and the captcha is working.

Comment: The code that generates the image uses `header` and that is one of the functions that will break if any output occurs before `header` is called - so to answer your question "can I add HTML code on the same captcha file" then no unless you also use output buffering - best option is to do as @KenLee said and place the captcha code in it's own file and call as the img src